# Test value exists and return boolean accordingly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm kind of new to SQL and I have been struggling to get the result I want.

I have these tables :

[image: 3 tables]

And my goal is to produce this :

[image: expected output]

For translation purposes : emprunt == borrowed, livre == book, oeuvre == collection

So my goal is to get all the books id (id_livre), their collection name (titre) and a boolean :
TRUE if they're borrowed (id_livre in emprunt table)
FALSE otherwise

I've done this :

```
SELECT livre.id_livre, titre, id_emprunt
FROM livre NATURAL JOIN oeuvre LEFT JOIN emprunt ON livre.id_livre = emprunt.id_livre
ORDER BY id_livre;
```

And got this output :

[image: Output I have so far]

So I'm close to what I want I believe but I don't know how to have a test returning a boolean instead of id_emprunt in the 3rd column

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "PL/SQL" is a procedural language specific to Oracle RDBMS.  You appear to be using SQL in Postgres.

Comment: Please [don't post code as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) see here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I removed the PL/SQL tag as that was completely wrong. And the screenshots clearly show that Postgres is being used, not Oracle.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know that, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT l.id_livre, l.titre,
       (CASE WHEN e.id_emprunt IS NOT NULL THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END) as est_emprunte
FROM livre l JOIN
     oeuvre o
     USING (id_livre) LEFT JOIN
     emprunt e
     USING (id_livre)
ORDER BY id_livre;
```

Oracle does not have a built-in boolean type, so you can settle for the letters `'t'` and `'f'`.  If it did (and some databases do) you would use:

```
   (e.id_emprunt IS NOT NULL) as est_emprunte
```

Note that I replaced the `NATURAL JOIN`.  I use the word "abomination" to describe it (partly in contrast to the word "natural" which is not appropriate).  The reason why I strongly oppose using it is because it does not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.  It is also dangerous, because the columns used for joining are not clear in the query, so I think it is a bad practice for that reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close as you said.  You could use a `CASE` statement on the third column to change the output to `t` or `f` dependent upon the value of `id_emprunt`:

```
SELECT livre.id_livre,
       titre,
       CASE
         WHEN id_emprunt IS NULL THEN 'f'
         ELSE 't'
       END AS est_emprunte
  FROM livre NATURAL JOIN oeuvre LEFT JOIN emprunt ON livre.id_livre = emprunt.id_livre
  ORDER BY id_livre;
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to use CASE. so:

```
SELECT livre.id_livre
       , titre
       , CASE WHEN id_emprunt IS NULL THEN 'f'
         ELSE 't' END AS est_emprunte 
FROM livre 
LEFT JOIN oeuvre 
USING(id_oeuvre)
LEFT JOIN emprunt 
USING(id_livre)
ORDER BY id_livre
```